# I have a video gallery try to get videos files from a specific directory i am getting an error parameters cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, android, video-gallery

I am making a video gallery trying to get videos files from a specific directory i am getting an error parameters cannot be resolved to a variable here is my code of the gallery activity.I am a newbie to java and my English is not that good.Thanks in advance for helping.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class Main extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {
  Cursor cursor;

  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
    String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"/storage/sdcard0/phd"};
    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            parameters, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");



    ListView listView = (ListView) this.findViewById(R.id.ListView);

    String[] thumbColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA,
        MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID };

    String[] mediaColumns = { MediaStore.Video.Media._ID,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA, MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE,
        MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE };


    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
        mediaColumns, null, null, null);

    ArrayList<VideoViewInfo> videoRows = new ArrayList<VideoViewInfo>();

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
      do {

        VideoViewInfo newVVI = new VideoViewInfo();
        int id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Media._ID));
        Cursor thumbCursor = managedQuery(
            MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            thumbColumns, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.VIDEO_ID
                + "=" + id, null, null);
        if (thumbCursor.moveToFirst()) {
          newVVI.thumbPath = thumbCursor.getString(thumbCursor
              .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.DATA));
          Log.v("", newVVI.thumbPath);
        }

        newVVI.filePath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA));
        newVVI.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.TITLE));
        Log.v("", newVVI.title);
        newVVI.mimeType = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE));
        Log.v("", newVVI.mimeType);
        videoRows.add(newVVI);
      } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    listView.setAdapter(new VideoGalleryAdapter(this, videoRows));
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
  }

  public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> l, View v, int position, long id) {
    if (cursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
      int fileColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA);
      int mimeColumn = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Video.Media.MIME_TYPE);
      String videoFilePath = cursor.getString(fileColumn);
      String mimeType = cursor.getString(mimeColumn);
      Intent intent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
      File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);
      intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(newFile), mimeType);
      startActivity(intent);
    }
  }
}
class VideoViewInfo {
  String filePath;
  String mimeType;
  String thumbPath;
  String title;
}

class VideoGalleryAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context context;
  private List<VideoViewInfo> videoItems;

  LayoutInflater inflater;

  public VideoGalleryAdapter(Context _context,
      ArrayList<VideoViewInfo> _items) {
    context = _context;
    videoItems = _items;

    inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
  }

  public int getCount() {
    return videoItems.size();
  }

  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return videoItems.get(position);
  }

  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View videoRow = inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    ImageView videoThumb = (ImageView) videoRow
        .findViewById(R.id.ImageView);
    if (videoItems.get(position).thumbPath != null) {
      videoThumb.setImageURI(Uri
          .parse(videoItems.get(position).thumbPath));
    }

    TextView videoTitle = (TextView) videoRow
        .findViewById(R.id.TextView);
    videoTitle.setText(videoItems.get(position).title);

    return videoRow;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you specify the line number on which you are getting error?

Comment: line number four right below oncreate String selection=MediaStore.Video.Media.DATA +" like?";
    String[] selectionArgs=new String[]{"/storage/sdcard0/phd"};
    cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Video.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            parameters, selection, selectionArgs, MediaStore.Video.Media.DATE_TAKEN + " DESC");